# What are some practical considerations for performing a "dredge" using Bayesian models?

Tags: bayesian, computational-statistics, model-comparison

I have been trying to find examples of cases where something along the lines of a dredge technique has been used in the Bayesian context. That is, specifying a global model and fitting all possible sub-models. Of course, if you are just specifying a plain ol' linear model, the number of possible sub-models doubles for every parameter you add.

So, when working in the Bayesian context, the first thing that comes to mind is computational effort. It may take substantially longer to fit a single model (assuming you need numerical methods to estimate a posterior) than it would by maximum likelihood, so as the global model grows in complexity, I could see it becoming prohibitive to fit hundreds or even thousands of sub-models in the Bayesian framework.

Additionally, to ensure you have actually sampled the target posterior, it is necessary to check convergence through visual (e.g. trace plots) or statistical (e.g. Gelman-Rubin) diagnostics. Again, more complex model requires at much more time spent checking convergence for all sub-models.

That's all I have so far. But I am kind of suspicious that I haven't really found anything on this yet, it makes me think I'm missing something completely obvious, in which case please point that out to me! With that, I would like to leave you with these questions:

1. Criticisms on model dredging aside, does it even make sense to dredge with Bayesian models?
2. If so, and you wanted to dredge a linear model having 10 parameters (so 1024 possible models) and know that you will need MCMC to sample the posterior, what would YOU consider in order to perform the fitting and checking in as efficient of a manner as possible?

For example, do you even need to re-fit all of the models as for the global model, or is there a way to estimate the posterior of each in a straightforward way? Or - just had this thought - is the posterior of a sub-model simply the marginal distribution of those specific parameters from the posterior of the global model?

I'm fairly inexperienced with Bayesian modeling in general, so please let me know of any resources that might help me understand this more.

Comment: What is the goal of this technique? Feature selection?

Comment: Essentially, yes. I am interested in comparing what variables are selected for in the top models for the same set of models (i.e. combinations of the global model's variables) fit to a number of exchangeable data sets.